# Creating a UISearchBar and UITableView inside a UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Disclaimer: I'm something of an iOS n00b. I have a navigation-based app -- i.e., in my AppDelegate, I create the nav frame:

```
self.navigation_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home_view_controller];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = navigation_controller;
self.window.makeKeyAndVisible;
```

Inside the frame of my home view, I want a search bar, then the scrollable table view. So, I wrote this:

```
- viewDidLoad{
  (HomeView*)home_view = [[HomeView alloc] init];
  self.view = home_view
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]

  (UITableView*)self.table_view = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  self.table_view.bounds.origin.y += 44;
  self.table_view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
  self.table_view.dataSource = self;
  self.table_view.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:self.table_view];

  search_frame = self.view.bounds;
  search_frame.origin.y = 48.0;
  search_frame.size.height = 48.0;

  self.search_bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:search_frame)];
  [self.view addSubview:self.search_bar];
}
```

The table view displays fine, but occupies all the space below the navigation bar. I want to have the navigation bar, then immediately below it the search bar, followed by the table view. At the point of `viewDidLoad`, the `UITableView` does not yet have a non-zero bounding rect and I expect that's part of the problem. Additionally, I've specified `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` in my `autoresizingMask` when I really want it glued against the search bar -- again, I believe this may be part of the problem.

What have I misunderstood here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve,

Try following changes:

1) Set tableview's frame using:

```
CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(0, 48, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.heigth);
(UITableView*)self.table_view = [UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:targetRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

2) Add following autosize mask also:

```
// This value will anchor your table view with top margin
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
```

3) Set searchbar's frame to following rect frame:

```
CGRecttMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 48);
```

Comment: What I wound up doing is making the search bar toggle triggered by a search icon in the nav bar, which is a bit sexier anyhow :) What I was not getting was the way autoresizemasks work, AFAICT. My solution works around this by not caring that the UITableView takes up all the view area left by the UINavigationView. Because the search bar now covers the top entry in the table, I probably should inset the table so that is still visible...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is just add the UISearchBar as the first UITableView header.

(method: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`)

Check this blog post:
http://jainmarket.blogspot.com/2009/08/add-searchbar-as-uitableviews-header.html